# Picking the lowest valued card that's higher than the one on the table (President card game)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to implement a card game called President (Player vs. 2 botplayers). So let's say a botplayer has the following hand:

```
tablecards = ['2 of Hearts']

bot_hand = ['6 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades', '4 of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', '7 of Hearts', 'King of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', '5 of Spades', 'King of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts']
```

The bot needs to select (and append to tablecards) the lowest valued card that's higher than the one on the table (2 of Hearts). So in this example hand it should pick 3 of Diamonds, if 3 of Diamonds is not available it should pick 4 of Diamonds, if 4 of Diamonds is not available it should pick 5 of Clubs and so on.

How would I implement such a condition? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. Use the [split function](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) to split on the space character `' '`.
2. Use the [parse function](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) to split using the format `"{} of {}"`.
3. Instead of storing the cards as a string, store them in a structured format, like a class or a tuple.

Also note that you may want to use the `int` function to convert a string to an int before comparison (`"10"` is less than `"2"`, but `int("10")` is greater than `int("2")`).

To pick up the min from the list, you can use the [min function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), using the `key` argument. Eg:

```
min(["2 of Clubs", "3 of Diamonds", "10 of Clubs"], key = lambda s: int(s.split(" ")[0]))
```

Note that you will need a slightly more complicated key to take care of Ace, King, Queen and Jack. Maybe you could create a dictionary to convert these strings into numbers.

```
specialCards = {"Jack": 11, "Queen": 12, "King": 13, "Ace": 14}
def key(card):
    s = card.split(' ')[0]
    if s in specialCards:
        return specialCards[s]
    else:
        return int(s)
```

Comment: Yes I can access the values like this: `for card in bot_hand:
        card_value = card.split()[0]`, but I'm still not sure how the bot should pick the right card.

Comment: Have a look at the "key" argument of the min function. I've edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only really caring about the values of the card, id suggest breaking the string down using some form of string manipulation then converting the value of that cards into integers.

With that find the highest value and the respective indexed card and get the bot to play that.

If in the future you do what the suit to take a role, id recommend having a look at min-max trees - But this is a notable increase in difficulty

Comment: Yes, only the values matter so I could put the card values in a new list like: `card_values = [] for card in bot_hand:
        card_value = card.split()[0]

        if 'Jack' in card:
            card_values.append(11)
        elif 'Queen' in card:
            card_values.append(12)
        elif 'King' in card:
            card_values.append(13)
        elif 'Ace' in card:
            card_values.append(14)
        else:
            card_values.append(int(card_value))` This is kinda as far as I got really.